# Something strange with ajax

Tags: ajax

```
function __construct(){
        $ajax = add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', array($this, 'ajax_respone'));
        var_dump($ajax);
        var_dump($ajax == '1234');
        die();
    }

    public function ajax_respone(){
        $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
        return $whatever;
    }
```

It prints:

> bool(true)
> bool(true)

How it is possible that `'1234'` or just `1234` is equal to true? Helps only `===`

Also just noticed that the `die()` in next code doesn't work

```
function __construct(){
    add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', array($this, 'ajax_respone'));
}

public function ajax_respone(){
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    var_dump($whatever);
    die();
}
```

This means that the function will not start or it starts only when requested?

Comment: take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php and you will see why `'1234'` and `1234` are equal to true in Loose comparisons with `==`

Comment: Well, yes - the function `ajax_respone()` will only execute when its called upon (in this case when you send a request to **admin-ajax.php** with the variable `action` set to "_my_action_" in the request data). How do you know that your call to `die()` isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

add_action and add_filter always return true.

And yes, in PHP, any string that is not empty or "0" is loosely equal to the boolean true.

And I see nothing wrong with your die code. It's hooked to wp_ajax_my_action, so you need to make a call to the admin-ajax.php as an authenticated user, with the my_action request. Then it will die.